# set_index not working as expected on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

In my code I have a function as follows, that returns a simple dataframe:

```
def find_highest_confs(dictOfCurves):
"""
Parameters
----------
dictOfCurves : Function takes in a dictionary containing stocks(key) and a 
dataframe per stock containing stocktrend data for that stock

Returns
-------
multipleConfs : A dataframe with per row the stock (ticker symbol), start 
date of the highest order trend, the nr of times that trend was confirmed 
and the date of last confirmation

"""
multipleConfs = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['symbol', 'max confirmations', \
                                        'Launch date', 'Last confirmation'])
for item in dictOfCurves:

    df            = dictOfCurves[item]
    
    try:
        df.sort_values(by = ['confirmations'], ascending = False, inplace = True)    

        maxLaunchDate = df[df['confirmations'] == df['confirmations'].max()].index[0]
        lastConf      = df.loc[maxLaunchDate, 'Last confirmation']
        newData       = {'symbol': item, 'max confirmations': df['confirmations'].max(), \
                         'Launch date': maxLaunchDate, 'Last confirmation': lastConf} 
    except:
        newData       = {'symbol': item, 'max confirmations': np.nan, 'Launch date': np.nan, \
                         'Last confirmation': np.nan} 

    multipleConfs     = multipleConfs.append(newData, ignore_index = True)

return multipleConfs
```

Now this code works fine, and returns a df, like so:

```
highest = find_highest_confs(curves)
```

which results in a dataframe as expected, with no index set.

if I then set an index like so:

```
highest.set_index('symbol', inplace = True)
```

that again, **works like expected.**

Here is the weird thing...

If I change the last line in the function to:

```
return multipleConfs.set_index('symbol', inplace = True)
```

it returns an empty `NoneType`?

I also tried add the `multipleConfs.set_index('symbol', inplace = True)` 
statement one line earlier and then returning it. Same result?

I am really confused as to why I can't set the index as part of the code in the function?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can't use `inplace` parameter here.    Inplace returns None object.  Remove 'inplace' parameter.  Or do this line before the return and `return multipleConfs`.  With `inplace = False` (default if not defined), this statement does return the dataframe object.

```
return multipleConfs.set_index('symbol')
```

or

```
multipleConfs.set_index('symbol', inplace = True)
return multipleConfs
```

Comment: That is exactly what I thought should work, but doesn't? If I do as you suggest, it returns an *empty* dataframe. If i do not set the index (as per the code in my original post) it returns the dataframe as expected. ???

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the dataframe column in the argument:

```
multipleConfs.set_index(multipleConfs['symbol'])
```